# Rendering rows in React Native's ListView component

Tags: react-native

I'm having no trouble create a `ListView`, but I find that if i want to render that `ListView` inside of a `View` it breaks and the scroll no longer works.

I understand that two elements can't be next to one another without being wrapped in a parent `View` but that breaks my `ListView`. My `ListView` is rendered the following way, within a React Component named `Main`.

```
renderMeeting(meeting) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.imaging}>
                <Image source={{uri: meeting.Picture}} style={styles.thumbnail} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.meetingTime}>
                  {meeting.Time}
                </Text>
            <View style={styles.firstRow}>
                <Text style={styles.meetingName}>
                  {meeting.Name}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.Title}>
                  {meeting.Title}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.Company}>
                  @ {meeting.Company}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.meetingDescription}>
                  {meeting.Description}
                </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.borderLine} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
  }

  render() {
  return(
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderMeeting.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView} />  
      ); 
  }

};
```

When my `render` method in `index.ios.js` just returns this `Main` component, it works just fine:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Main>
  );
}
```

However, if I attempt to wrap `Main` within a `View`, it does not work:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Main>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If I want anything to float over the `ListView` or if I want to have it only be half page I can't seem to get it to work as long as this component is anywhere is a parent view.

Answer (score 3):

Probably what's happening is the outer view is ending up with a 0 height. You should be able to fix things by giving it a `flex` style of `1`.

```
render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Main>
  </View>
  );
}
```

Using `flex: 1` as a style seems to do the trick for container views like this so it could look something like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```